# Babel plugin not being recognized when trying to run Jest

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

I'm just starting to write some Jest tests but have immediately run into an "unknown plugin" error in what otherwise appeared to be a fully working Webpack/Babel setup that functions fine at the `npm run dev`/`npm run build` stage.

Specifically, I'm getting `ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "@babel/transform-async-to-generator" specified in "C:\\Users\\scott\\path\\to\\ThisProject\\.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "C:\\Users\\scott\\path\\to\\ThisProject"`

(Error reads that way as I'm in Git Bash on Windows.)

I definitely have `@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator` installed.

The relevant part of my `package.json` looks like:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest",
  "build": "webpack --mode=production",
  "dev": "webpack --mode=development"
},
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.1.0",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.1.0",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
  "webpack": "^4.20.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "ajv": "^6.5.4",
  "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
  "eslint": "^5.8.0",
  "jest": "^23.6.0",
  "jsdom": "^13.0.0",
}
```

My `.babelrc` is very simple:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "ie": "11"
                },
                "useBuiltIns": "entry"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/transform-async-to-generator",
        "@babel/transform-arrow-functions",
        "@babel/transform-modules-commonjs"
    ],
    "env": {
        "development": {},
        "test": {},
        "production": {}
    }
}
```

Likewise `jest.config.js` which is straight out of `jest --init`:

```json
module.exports = {
    clearMocks: true,
    coverageDirectory: "coverage",
    testEnvironment: "jsdom"
};
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `npm install --save-dev babel-jest babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge @babel/core`, I believe the babel team released a bridge package to aid dependencies that are affected by the v7 upgrade.

See here for more info: https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest#usage

Comment: Boy howdy!!! That was the solution. There's a faint chance I might have stumbled on it myself but not at this time of day after flailing for hours. Thanks a bunch!